# I want to use jQuery("#location").load or .get ("file.php") but only returns document.write output not html from php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I get that the jQuery .load function does indeed return the *results* from a load of a php file, but I don't want to convert every line of html inside my php file to be:

```
echo " ... ";
```

Inside my php file that I want to dynamically load into a div tag, I have a php include of another php file, 100+ lines of html code, and some javascript to create custom form content.

I want the resulting html from this php file to be loaded into the div tag.
Is jQuery load or get the right function, or do I need to explicitly write out the ajax code or something else?

Edit: Currently it only displays the document.write output from the JavaScript; none of the HTML code is displayed/returned from .load or .get.

File example:
inside index.php

```
jQuery("#mainContent").load("another.php");
```

also tried

```
jQuery("#mainContent").get("another.php");
```

and

```
$("#mainContent").load("another.php");
```

Here is the other file (snippet example) for another.php

<?php include 'navigation.php';  ?>

<b>Here comes the rain again...</b>

<script language="JavaScript">document.write("this part only is loaded");
  </script>

Comment: From what I understand, the return is a mixture of javascript and html. and you wish to load that code via ajax?

Comment: @Shoogle yes - I want the full another.php to be embedded within the div tag, including the include navigation.php file, the html code, and the results of the javascript document.write output.

Comment: Whenever using jQuery, i have always separated html with javascript. using dataType in $.ajax, i define whether the return data is a script, jSon or just HTML and on success process it.. giving complete control over the data returned and the way I use it

Comment: so instead of using .load, i should use the .ajax command and how do I specify that it is just HTML? thanks!

Comment: dataType can be
xml, json, script, or html

Answer (score 2):

*"I want the resulting html from this php file to be loaded into the div tag"*

Well, that's exactly what `.load` does:

```
$('#target').load('http://www.example.com/page.php');
```

Loads the content of `http://www.example.com/page.php` into the element named `target`.

If this isn't working, you need to be clearer on what the problem is.

Comment: I added as an edit to my question. the .load is ONLY returning info from document.write( and NONE of the html code. Can you help?

Comment: Do you mean the result of the above answer is only printing "this part only is loaded" and not the above line "<b>Here comes the rain again...</b>"

Comment: It will evaluate the script tag - which isn't the same as embedding the content in the div. Perhaps a silly question, but does #mainContent exist?

Comment: @Hamish - yes of course mainContent exists as I stated the document.write output is all working correctly.

Comment: script tags evaluate even if the target doesn't exist, so that's not actually a guarantee that #mainContent exists. Could you post the actual page source to pastebin?

Comment: ah you might be on to something Hamish

Comment: Using Chrome dev tools I drilled down into the iframe (facebook app) and found that Hamish you're right - the document.write code inside the loading php file is wiping out the entire iframe'd html file! which explains why i can see the output of the document.write codes but none of the formatting. So that leaves us with the same question - how do you dynamically include into a div tag a php file that also has javascripting in it?

Comment: wow - how retarted. I just wrote up a beautiful answer fully showing how to implement and this website won't let me post an answer to my question for 8 hours. Lame!  Good luck peeps!

Answer (score 0):

So based on the discussions, it appears that **it is NOT possible to load a php file that contains a mix of php, html, and javascript document.write in it and put that within a div tag in another file dynamically.**

What IS possible, at least the only solution I have found thus far, is to include the php file with other php code and html and even a script tag but NO document.write in it. 
To add the customizations I had in the document.write javascript, I instead used the following example to send the javascript variables to the php file, have it process it as a php variable and send back the full file. (Based on: [Jquery load() and PHP variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479974/jquery-load-and-php-variables) )

```
$('#mainContent').load( "another.php", 
  {
    'key1': js_array['key'],
    'key2': js_variable_value
  } 
);
```

Then the parameters are posted to the file test.php and are accessible as:

```
<?php
$key1 = $_POST['key1']
$key2 = $_POST['key2']
?>
// some html code
...
<img alt="photograph" src="<?php echo $key1; ?>" />
```

Would love to know a better solution.