# Best way to refresh multiple PHP values every x seconds?

Tags: php, jquery

I have an `index.php` file that I would like to run `getdata.php` every 5 seconds.

`getdata.php` returns multiple variables that need to be displayed in various places in `index.php`.

I've been trying to use the jQuery `.load()` function with no luck.
It's refreshing the 12 `<div>` elements in various places on the `index.php`, but it's not re-running the `getdata.php` file that should get the newest data.

But If I hit the browser refresh button, the data is refreshed.

`getdata.php` returns about 15 variables.

Here is some sample code:

```
<script>
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
         $('#Hidden_Data').load('GetData.php'); // Shouldn´t this return $variables
         $('#Show_Data_001').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
         $('#Show_Data_002').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
         $('#Show_Data_003').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
         $('#...').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
    }, 5000); // Data refreshed every 5 seconds
    */
</script>
```

Here's an example of `GetData.php`:

```
$query = "SELECT column1, COUNT(column2) AS variable FROM table GROUP BY column";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$column1 = $row['column1 '];
$variable = $row['variable '];

if($column1 == "Text1") { $variable1 = $variable; }
    elseif($column1 == "Text2") { $variable2 = $variable; }
              ... continues to variable 15 ...
}
```

Then further down the page the HTML elements display the data:

```
<div id="Hidden_Data"></div>
<div id="Show_Data_001"><?php echo $variable1; ?></div>
<div id="Show_Data_002"><?php echo $variable2; ?></div>
<div id="Show_Data_003"><?php echo $variable3; ?></div>
...
```

I tried using the data parameter as suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480059/498596

But I couldn't fully understand how to load all the variables every 5 seconds and call them on the index page.

Today the `GetData.php` page just returns `$variable1 = X; $variable2 = Y` and so on.

**UPDATE**
For some reason the jQuery is not loading the `GatData.php` file and refreshing the variables.

I tried adding to "Hidden_Data" to the `include('GetData.php')` and then the variables are readable on the page.

If I remove this part, the page displays "variable not set" warning that suggesting that the jQuery is not loading the `GetData.php` script into the `Hidden_Data` `<div>`.

Comment: Are the `Show_Data_001`, 2 and 3 elements inside `Hidden_Data` and  returned by `GetData.php`, or are they already on your page somewhere else?

Comment: I have "Hidden_Data" outside as a seperate element. Just added that to the code above.

Comment: The `.load()` method loads content into the specified element (`Hidden_Data`), it does _not_ refresh the rest of the page in a general sense and more specifically it doesn't know anything about PHP variables. The browser doesn't know or care that the page had dynamic content set from PHP - what you see when you use the browser's "View Page Source" option is what the browser received. If the point of `GetData.php` is just to return new values for those variables it would be better to change it to return JSON, and then use the jQuery `$.getJSON()` method to call it and process the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 <script>
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
             $('#Hidden_Data').load('GetData.php', function() { // Shouldn´t this return $variables
                 $('#Show_Data_001').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
                 $('#Show_Data_002').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
                 $('#Show_Data_003').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
                 $('#...').fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow"); });
        }, 5000); // Data refreshed every 5 seconds
        */
    </script>
```

Above is assuming, that your code returns snippet of HTML elements (Show_Data_XXX), but now that you've clarified your question above wont help you alone...

What you need to do is either in your php send back new value elements or send back your results as data and update existing elements.

Put your elements into a php Array and then send it back
data.php after sql call

```
$results = Array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $column1 = $row['column1 ']; // change Text1 in db to Show_Data_001 in html or vice versa
   $variable = $row['variable '];
   $results[$column1] = $variable;
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

in your javascript something like this...

```
$.getJSON('GetData.php',function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $('#'+key).text(val);
  });
});
```

I didn't put the fadeOut and fadeIn into the example, because it complicates it a bit. You could do fadeOut to all those elements before calling getJSON and the fadeIn as the results pouring in. Hope this helps

Comment: I can´t seem to get this to work. The DIV is fading in and out, but it´s not getting the newest variable updates from GetData.php

Comment: I see you've given more input. I assumed that your GetData.php replaces the #Hidden_Data div data with the elements #Show_Data_XXX. If you are actually returning data in some format. You need to insert it to your data elements. For example store your results into PHP array and then json_encode it. You can then use jquery parseJSON function to turn it back to an array. I'll modify my answer a bit.

Comment: Good to hear! Keep on coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you have correct respond from server, just like this:

```
//We won't use load() to load content for now
window.setInterval(function(){

   $.ajax({
      url : "path_to_your_php_script.php",
      type : "GET",
      beforeSend: function(){
         //here you can display, smth like "Please wait" in some div
      },
      error : function(msg){
         //You would know if an error occurs  
         alert(msg);
      },
      success : function(respondFromPHP){
         //Are you getting distinct results every 5 sec?
         alert(respondFromPHP);
         return;
         //if respondFromPHP contains data you want
         //ONLY THEN, add some effects
      }
    });

}, 5000);
```

The only difference between this approach and yours, is that, you can handle errors and make sure you are getting data you want.

Comment: This would actually solve my issue. I´ve been trying to solve how to then return the php variable data and print them out in various DIVs on the page. Just can´t figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me the code of GetData.php?

Rather than using Jquery.load you can actually get the page with $.post or $.get and format your results from GetData.php to Json or xml you can easily map it to your javascript.

Using $.post it will allow you to have a callback after getting the value from GetData.php and you can check it if it's working right or not. If it gets a data from your GetData.php then you can populate it to your DIV elements.

You can check more information regarding POST and GET here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Hi, I just added a demo of GetData.php to the original post.