# jquery load pass variable to php file

Tags: php, jquery, load

I want to pass a variable to a php file using load. based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479974/jquery-load-and-php-variables), I tried that :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#div2").load('loadTable.php',{
        'videoId': <?php echo $video_id ?>
    } );
    $("#div3").load("multiTimeline.php?videoid="+videoId+"");
});
```

It works perfectly fine like that(EDIT) :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#div2").load('loadTable.php'); 
});
```

In the debugger I can see that it doesn't even open the **loadTable.php**. Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I don't know if it is this but are you closing the `$( document ).ready(function() {` ? Because in your sample it insn't closed and the code is correct so if it isn't working it may be because of one simple detail

Comment: like that it works:
  $( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#div2").load('loadTable.php');
   $("#div3").load("multiTimeline.php");  });

Comment: So it was that the problem?

Comment: But that doesn't work:
[code]  $( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#div2").load('loadTable.php', 
    {    'videoId': <?php echo $video_id ?>  } );

   $("#div3").load("multiTimeline.php?videoid="+videoId+"");
});    [code]

Comment: where is `$video_id` being declared in the first example? Ass the php code to your question please

Comment: above in the code:  $video_id = '153fb143';     using the chrome debugger I can see that the varibale is recognized:    $( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#div2").load('loadTable.php', 
    {    'videoId': 153fb143  } );

   $("#div3").load("multiTimeline.php?videoid="+videoId+"");
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the update: This task was solved [here](http://www.jquery-board.de/threads/3837-Variable-an-PHP-file-schicken-mittels-load?p=15825#post15825)

I forgot to put this code (   )  in ''

It works like this:

```
$("#div2").load('loadTable.php', { 'videoId': '<?php echo $video_id ?>'  } );
```