# Define/Defined function

Tags: php

I Have two pages that I created a simple code with jquery and php

1st page

```
<?php
if(!defined("link")){
exit("hata");

}
?>
```

And second page

```
<?php
define("link",true);
?>
<script>
$("#load").load("sayfa.php");
</script>
```

Why first page is not working on second page using jquery?

Comment: When you say the first page is 'not working', what do you mean?  Do you see an error message?

Comment: Remember that PHP is executed on the server, and that each request starts without any knowlege of any other requests that have been made.  If that is the full content of the code of your first page, it will always call `exit("hata");` because that constant is not defined

Comment: If you want to set something on one page request, and retrieve that same value on a subsequent request, then you should probably look into using sessions https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: @RobEyre, when i write following code on second page,

Comment: @RobEyre, <?php
if(!defined("link")){
exit("hata");

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding the expectation was that since you have defined the `link` in the `second file` when you run the load command it will not print `hata` and be treated like it was defined.

Basically, all the PHP code is run on the server side and any variables are destroyed once the PHP execution is completed and just the values get utilized by the `HTML/JS` page that is created.

Since the `sayfa.php (first)` page is being loaded by javascript it is safe to assume that all PHP variables have already been removed by that point including the define.

Check this question for reference and how variables can be used if needed.

[Jquery load() and PHP variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479974/jquery-load-and-php-variables)

Comment: php define function is not work when i use jquery load

Comment: @shukurgumbatov Yes it will not, I have tried to explain that with the answer. 
Just for the sake of understanding think of the flow like this. `[Start PHP]` -> `[Run all PHP code in file]` -> `[Delete all PHP Variables]` -> `[Render the HTML to Browser]` -> `[Start Javascript]` -> `[Jquery Load]` -> `[Start PHP]` -> `[Run all PHP code in second file]` -> `[Delete all PHP Variables]` -> `[Send HTML to Jquery Load result]`.

The above is just to simplify the explanation for this particular case, actually what happens is a little more complex.

Comment: deepanshu223, it does not have other way yes?

Comment: @shukurgumbatov the way things are currently it won't work, you can refer to the link in my answer to view possible ways to use variables with Jquery Load, I am not listing them here as it is already well covered in the answers on the linked question.

Answer (score -1):

I think Your problem depends on how to show data in your file sayfa.php (print, echo etc, ex: print "hata";)
Then the loading function will work correctly

Comment: I want use with Jquery

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).